# Get GeoJson feature by ID and zoom on entity

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, jquery

I have got a leaflet map with Geojson layers :
[image]

I use jquery Autocomplete to search an entity by name or id, I have no problem with that. 
I need your help because I'm not able to refer to a specific point in my layer  (without a click on the map). Ideally, I would zoom in on it and open a popup.

Here is my code for loading Geojson markers :

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({showCoverageOnHover: false,disableClusteringAtZoom: 9});
        var points_rand = L.geoJson(points, {
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) //functionality on click on feature
                {
                    //ARRAY FOR AUTOCOMPLETE
                    musees_names_array.push(feature.properties.nom_musee, feature.properties.id);
                    //ARRAY KEY VALUE
                    musees_key_value[feature.properties.nom_musee] = feature.properties.id;

                    {
                var title_ = "<p class = \"leaf_title\">"+feature.properties.nom_musee+"</p>";
                var subtitle = "";
                var ouverture = "";
                if(feature.properties.site_web != null ){
                    subtitle +="<b>Site web : </b>"
                    +"<a href=\"http://"+feature.properties.site_web+"\">"+feature.properties.site_web+"</a></br>";
                }
                if(feature.properties.periode_ouverture != null ){
                    subtitle +="<b>Horaires : </b>"
                    +" <div class = \"leaf_ouverture\">"+feature.properties.periode_ouverture+"</div></br>";
                }
                    }
                layer.bindPopup(
                    title_ + subtitle + ouverture
                    )
                layer.setIcon(IconPerso);
                }
            });
```

After a research with Autocomplete I have a function with the id selected but I don't know how zoom on a specific marker :

```
$(function() {
$("#search_musee").autocomplete(
    {
        source:musees_names_array,
        minLength: 3,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
                var id_musee = musees_key_value[ui.item.value];// ID selected
                //HERE IS MY PROBLEM
                //I would like something like :
                // map.fitBounds(SPECIFIC_MARKER.getBounds());
        }
    })
```

});

I did some research like [trigger event leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421127/how-to-trigger-events-on-leaflet-map-polygons) but without success,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a hash inside the `onEachFeature` function:

```js
musees_layers[feature.properties.nom_musee] = musees_layers[feature.properties.id] = layer;
```

Then just use it in autocomplete `select` event:

```js
select: function( event, ui ) {
    var layer = musees_layers[ui.item.value];

    //for markers
    map.setView(layer.getLatLng(), DEFAULT_ZOOM);

    //for polygons/polylines
    //map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this issue ! I have now a new problem, some layers (polygon) don't a "_leaflet_id" property. entity_key_dep[feature.properties.code_dept] = layer._leaflet_id; console.log(layer._leaflet_id);

Comment: I have got sometimes "undefined" and sometimes a correct leaflet id in firebug ....

Comment: Use function `L.stamp(layer)` - it adds internal Leaflet's ID to the layer (which you can see as `_leaflet_id` property) and returns that ID.